# Not able to aggregate data returned from the twilio api

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, twilio

I'm trying to fetch the billing data from the Twilio API and save the returned value in a variable so that I can return it and display it in my web app. I know it's related to async, I tried using async and await but wasn't able to make it work.

```
const twilio = require("twilio");

client = twilio(
  "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "AUTHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
);

const filterOpts = {
  startDate: "2021-08-01",
  endDate: "2021-08-31",
};

let result = []
function getBillingData() {
  client.usage.records.each(filterOpts, async (record) => {
    let temp = await record;
    result.push(temp);
  });
}


getBillingData();
console.log(result.length);
```

When I try to run this, it prints `0`

Comment: Need a link to the documentation for `client.usage.records.each()`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'm not very sure but I this the closest match I can find. 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.70.0/Twilio.Supersim.V1.UsageRecordList.html

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks for the help, I was able to find an answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
const filterOpts = {
  startDate: "2021-08-02",
  endDate: "2021-08-02",
  callback: (data) => {result.push(data);} ,
  done: () => {console.log(result.length);},
};


async function getBillingData() {
  client.usage.records.each(filterOpts);
}

async function getData() {
  await getBillingData();
};

getData();
```

I went through the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.70.0/Twilio.Supersim.V1.UsageRecordList.html) to find the that I can pass two optional parameters which would do my work.

Comment: The_iceman, from the documentation, I understand that instead of `.each()`, you should be using `.list()`. which returns Promise-wrapped resources (results).  You just need to prepare your `filterOptions` with `.startDate` and `.endDate` properties; leave out `.callback` and `.done`. `.list()` will return a `Q` promise, which you can (and arguably should) cast to a native js promise with `Promise.resolve()` (or rely on an asyncFunction to do so automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think this issue is a race condition with asynchronous calls in your JS and you code returning before the asynchronous calls are finished. I think the `each` call is asynchronous too. Try this:

```js
async function getBillingData() {
  let result = []
  await client.usage.records.each(filterOpts, async (record) => {
    let temp = await record;
    result.push(temp);
  });
  return result;
}


getBillingData().then((result) => {
  console.log(result.length);
})
```

Now the `getBillingData` function is an `async` function, so it can use `await` on the call to `client.usage.records.each`. It also collects the `results` within itself and returns the value when the function resolves.

Finally, we use `getBillingData().then()` to ensure that the data is collected and returned before logging it.

Comment: Doesn't work, it still prints 0. 
Thanks for the help, I was finally able to find a way to do this.